# How do you customize the header of the Collection Editor?

Tags: c#, winforms, collectioneditor

I have a class that contains several public properties. I made a List containing instances of this class. Then I use PropertyGrid to edit objects of this List with a standard Collection Editor. I found out how to customize names of fields, but I still can't change the header of Collection Editor.

For example I want to replace "MyItemClass Collection Editor" with "My Favourite Item Collection Editor".

How can I change the header of Collection Editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inherit a custom class from [CollectionEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.collectioneditor(v=vs.110).aspx) class, override the [CreateCollectionForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.collectioneditor.createcollectionform(v=vs.110).aspx) method and modify the [Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159419(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the [CollectionForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.collectioneditor.collectionform(v=vs.110).aspx) instance returned by the base class:

```
class CustomEditor : CollectionEditor
{
    public CustomEditor(Type type)
        : base(type)
    {
    }

    protected override CollectionForm CreateCollectionForm()
    {
        CollectionForm collectionForm = base.CreateCollectionForm();

        collectionForm.Text = "My title";

        return collectionForm;
    }
}
```